# JS function doesn't recognize JavaScript interface method

Tags: javascript, android

I faced the following problem. There's a part of the webpage:

```
    document.getElementById('continueButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        window.parent.postMessage('PAYLANDS-ERROR', '*');

        if (window.parent.HTMLOUT) {
            window.parent.HTMLOUT.paylandsFail();
        }
    });
```

Here's my interface which contains methods with annotation @JavascriptInterface:

```
interface IAddCard3dsJavaScript {

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun paylandsSuccess()

    @JavascriptInterface
    fun paylandsFail()

    companion object {
        const val INTERFACE_NAME = "HTMLOUT"
    }

}
```

There's the class which implements this interface:

```
class AddCard3dsJavaScript(private val presenter: IAddCard3dsCallback) : IAddCard3dsJavaScript {

    override fun paylandsSuccess() {
        presenter.onPaylands3dsSuccess()
    }

    override fun paylandsFail() {
        presenter.onPaylands3dsFailed()
    }

}
```

But when I run the app I get this line in console: `Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.HTMLOUT.paylandsFail is not a function`. I tried to change the interface name to `window.parent.HTMLOUT` instead of `HTMLOUT`, and in this case, I didn't get the error, but `paylandsFail`  method body didn't execute. So, what's the problem and how can I solve it?

**UPD**

Here's the way how I add this interface to webview:

```
@SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    override fun loadUrlFor3ds(url: String) {
        addCardWebView?.apply {
            addJavascriptInterface(AddCard3dsJavaScript(getController()), IAddCard3dsJavaScript.INTERFACE_NAME)
            loadUrl(url)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding annotation `@JavascriptInterface` to `AddCard3dsJavaScript` - `IAddCard3dsJavaScript` implementation